# In Konva, how can I prevent a shape stroke disappearing on mouseover?

Tags: konvajs

I've added a rectangle to a Konva stage. I've given it a stroke. When I mouseover, the stroke disappears until I mouseout. I want the stroke to remain in place when I mouseover. Is that possible?

I've tried both strokeHitEnabled(false) and strokeHitEnabled(true), hoping that might have an effect but it doesn't.

```
rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
    x: simpleFrameX,
    y: simpleFrameY,
    width: simpleFrameWidth - simpleFrameStrokeWidth,
    height: simpleFrameHeight - simpleFrameStrokeWidth,
    fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
    stroke: simpleFrameStrokeColour,
    strokeWidth: simpleFrameStrokeWidth,
    draggable: true,
    name: 'productImage',
    id: 'id' + stagedImageCount
    });
stagedImageCount++;
layer.add(rect1);
layer.draw();
```

Comment: The effect you describe is definitely not standard behaviour. Check your code for unintended effects and post a cut-down sample, ideally as a running snippet. There is too little information in the code that you have posted as a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Deep in my development code I found where I'd actually made that happen myself and had forgotten to remove the strokeEnabled(false) and matching strokeEnabled(true).

```
<embarrassed>
```